# How to do simple random sampling with Spark Dstreams?(pyspark using spark 1.6.1)

Tags: pyspark, spark-streaming

I want to take sample from rdds in a Dstream. As Dstream doesn't have `sample()` transformation and it is a sequence of rdds so I did this to take sample from a Dstream and apply a wordcount on it:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

# Optionally configure Spark Settings
conf=SparkConf()
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")
conf.set("spark.cores.max", "2")

conf.setAppName("SRS")
 sc = SparkContext('local[3]', conf=conf)

from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
streamContext = StreamingContext(sc,3)
lines = streamContext.socketTextStream("localhost", 9000)

def sampleWord(rdd):
     return rdd.sample(false,0.5,10)


lineSample = lines.foreachRDD(sampleWord)
words = lineSample.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word , 1))
wordCount = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
wordCount.pprint(60)


streamContext.start()
streamContext.stop()
```

With this code, Spark starts but nothing exactly happens. I don't know why `rdd.sample()` doesn't work this way? Using `foreachRDD`, we can have access to each rdd in the stream, so I think now we can use the transformation which is specific for rdd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `transform` instead of `foreachRDD`. Also, there is a typo in your code.

```
def sampleWord(rdd):
 return rdd.sample(False,0.5,10) //False, not false

lineSample = lines.transform(sampleWord)
words = lineSample.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word , 1))
wordCount = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)
wordCount.pprint(60)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `transform`:

```
lineSample = lines.transform(sampleWord)
```

Comment: again there is an error in sampleWord => return rdd.sample(false,0.5,100)
: NameError: global name 'true' is not defined. And nothing happens. I don`t understand if spark is computing the sample or not..